# Generar archivo .HEX sin Arduino IDE

Tags: archivo, arduino, ide, compilador

Hola a todos y gracias de antemano, supongo que con el titulo la duda es obvia, estoy buscando información sobre el proceso que realiza el ide de Arduino al momento de subir el código a la tarjeta, se que archivos están involucrados al subir al micro controlador el archivo HEX que se genera, pero todavía no sé como es que de manera interna el ide de Arduino genera ese archivo ni que archivos y programas de este ide están involucrados. Me gustaría generar este archivo desde la consola de Windows o el terminal de Linux. Gracias otra vez y perdón por las molestias.

Comment: podrias usar el siguiente proyecto; https://github.com/arduino-cmake/arduino-cmake o https://github.com/sudar/Arduino-Makefile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Arduino - Entorno de desarrollo integrado para placas Arduino**

- **SINOPSIS**
  **arduino** [ FILE.ino ...]

**arduino** [ **--verify** | **--upload** ] [ **--board** paquete : arco : Junta [: **parámetros** ]] [ **--port** nombre de puerto ] [ **--pref** nombre = valor ] [ -v | **--verbose** ] [ **--preserve-temp-files** ] [ FILE.ino ]

**arduino** [ **--get-pref** [ preferencia ]]

**arduino** [ **--install-boards** nombre del paquete : plataforma arquitectura [: versión ]]

**arduino** [ **--install-library** nombre de la biblioteca [: versión ] [, nombre de la biblioteca [: versión ], nombre de la biblioteca [: versión ]]

**arduino** [ **--version** ]

- **DESCRIPCIÓN**

El Arduino entorno de desarrollo integrado permite edición, compilación y carga de bocetos (programas) para Arduino (y compatibles) tableros de microcontroladores.

Normalmente, ejecutar el comando arduino inicia el IDE, cargando opcionalmente cualquier archivo .ino especificado en la línea de comandos.

Alternativamente, si se da alguna de las siguientes opciones de línea de comando, no se mostrará ninguna interfaz gráfica y, en su lugar, se realizará una verificación única (compilación) o una carga. Se debe dar un solo archivo .ino. Si el boceto contiene múltiples archivos .ino, se puede especificar cualquiera en la línea de comandos, pero se compilará todo el boceto.

Cuando se ejecuta en modo único, puede ser útil establecer la preferencia build.path para permitir el mantenimiento de resultados de compilación intermedios entre varias ejecuciones y solo recompilar los archivos que cambiaron.

Tenga en cuenta que en MacOS X, el ejecutable principal es Arduino.app/Contents/MacOS/Arduino en lugar de arduino .

Tenga en cuenta que en Windows, debido a la diferencia entre la GUI y las aplicaciones de consola, arduino_debug.exe es el ejecutable apropiado para usar si desea usar la mayoría de estas opciones de línea de comando. La versión de GUI de arduino.exe del iniciador puede realizar algunas de las funciones que se describen a continuación, pero no generará ningún mensaje en la consola, lo que significa que es bastante inútil si desea recibir algún comentario o poder mantener archivos de registro para pruebas automatizadas. etc.

- **COMPORTAMIENTO**

**--verificar**
Construye el boceto.

**--subir**
Cree y cargue el boceto.

**--get-pref** [ preferencia ]
Imprime el valor de la preferencia dada en la secuencia de salida estándar. Cuando el valor no existe, no se imprime nada y se establece el estado de salida (ver SALIDA DE ESTADO a continuación). Si no se da preferencia como parámetro, imprime todas las preferencias.

**--install-boards** nombre del paquete : plataforma arquitectura [: versión ]
Busca la lista de soporte de la placa (plataforma) disponible e instala la especificada, junto con sus herramientas relacionadas. Si se omite la versión , se instala la última. Si una plataforma con la misma versión ya está instalada, no se instala nada y el programa sale con el código de salida 1. Si una plataforma con una versión diferente ya está instalada, se reemplaza.

**--install-library** nombre de la biblioteca [: versión ]
Las capturas de bibliotecas disponibles enumeran e instalan la especificada. Si se omite la versión , se instala la última. Si ya está instalada una biblioteca con la misma versión, no se instala nada y el programa sale con el código de salida 1. Si ya está instalada una biblioteca con una versión diferente, se reemplaza. Se pueden especificar múltiples bibliotecas, separadas por una coma.

**--versión**
Imprima la información de la versión y salga.

- **OPCIONES**

**paquete del tablero : arch : board [: parameters ]**

Seleccione la placa para compilar.

- paquete es el identificador del proveedor (las carpetas de primer nivel dentro del directorio de hardware ). Las placas arduino predeterminadas usan arduino .
- la arquitectura es la arquitectura de la placa (carpetas de segundo nivel dentro del directorio de hardware ). Las placas arduino predeterminadas usan arduino: avr para todas las placas basadas en AVR (como Uno, Mega o Leonardo) o arduino: sam para las placas basadas en SAM de 32 bits (como Arduino Due).
- board es la placa que se debe usar, tal como se define en boards.txt que se encuentra en la carpeta de arquitectura seleccionada. Por ejemplo, arduino: avr: uno para Arduino Uno, arduino: avr: diecimila para Arduino Duemilanove o Diecimila, o arduino: avr: mega para Arduino Mega.
- parámetros es una lista de tablas separadas por comas de parámetros específicos que normalmente se muestran debajo de los submenús del menú "Herramientas". Por ejemplo, arduino: avr: nano: cpu = atmega168 para seleccionar la variante mega168 de la placa Arduino Nano.

Si no se pasa esta opción, se usa el valor de las preferencias actuales (por ejemplo, la última tabla seleccionada en el IDE).

**--port** nombre de puerto
Seleccione el puerto serie para realizar la carga del boceto. En Linux y MacOS X, esta debería ser la ruta a un archivo de dispositivo (p. Ej., / Dev / ttyACM0 ). En Windows, este debería ser el nombre del puerto serie (p. Ej., COM3 ).

Si no se pasa esta opción, se utiliza el valor de las preferencias actuales (por ejemplo, el último puerto seleccionado en el IDE).

**--verbose-build**
Habilite el modo detallado durante la compilación. Si no se proporciona esta opción, el modo detallado durante la compilación se desactiva independientemente de las preferencias actuales.

**--preserve-temp-files**
Mantenga los archivos temporales (boceto preprocesado, archivos de objetos ...) después de la finalización. Si se omite, los archivos temporales se eliminan.

Esta opción solo es válida junto con --verify o --upload .

**--useprogrammer**
Cargar usando un programador. Establezca si está usando un programador externo o está usando Arduino como ISP.

**--verbose-upload**
Habilite el modo detallado durante la carga. Si no se proporciona esta opción, el modo detallado durante la carga se desactiva independientemente de las preferencias actuales.

Esta opción solo es válida junto con **--verify** o **--upload** .

**-v**, **--verbose**
Habilite el modo detallado durante la compilación y la carga. Esta opción tiene el mismo efecto que usar **--verbose-build** y **--verbose-upload** .

Esta opción solo es válida junto con **--verify** o **--upload** .

**--preferences-file** nombre de archivo
Lea y almacene preferencias del nombre de archivo especificado en lugar del predeterminado.

**--pref** nombre = valor
Establece el nombre de la preferencia al valor dado .

Tenga en cuenta que las preferencias que establece con esta opción no están validadas: los nombres inválidos se establecerán pero nunca se usarán; los valores no válidos pueden ocasionar un error más adelante.

**--save-prefs**
Guarde las preferencias (modificadas) en preferences.txt . En particular **--board** , **--port** , **--pref** , **--verbose** , **--verbose-build** y **--verbose-upload** pueden alterar las preferencias actuales.

- **PREFERENCIAS**

Arduino mantiene una lista de preferencias, como simples pares de nombre y valor. A continuación, algunos de ellos están documentados, pero hay muchos más disponibles.

**sketchbook.path**
La ruta donde los bocetos son (generalmente) almacenados. Esta ruta también puede contener algunos subdirectorios especiales (ver ARCHIVOS a continuación).

**comprobación de actualización**
Cuando se establece en verdadero, el IDE busca una nueva versión al inicio.

**editor.externo**
Cuando se establece en verdadero, use un editor externo (el IDE no permite editar y volver a cargar cada archivo antes de verificar).

**Construir camino**
El camino a usar para construir. Aquí es donde van cosas como el archivo .cpp preprocesado, los archivos .o compilados y el archivo .hex final.

Si se establece, este directorio ya debería existir antes de ejecutar el comando arduino.

Si no se establece esta preferencia (que normalmente es el caso), se crea una nueva carpeta de compilación temporal en cada ejecución y se elimina de nuevo cuando se cierra la aplicación.

- **SALIR ESTADO**

**0** : Éxito

**1** : Error de compilación o carga fallida

**2** : Boceto no encontrado

**3** : Opción de línea de comando inválida (argumento para)

**4** : La preferencia pasada a **--get-pref** no existe

- **ARCHIVOS**

**% LOCALAPPDATA% / Arduino15 / preferences.txt (Windows)**
**~ / Library / Arduino15 / preferences.txt (Max OS X)**
**~ / .arduino15 / preferences.txt (Linux)**
Este archivo almacena las preferencias usadas para el IDE, construyendo y cargando bocetos.

**Mis documentos / Arduino / (Windows)**
**~ / Documents / Arduino / (Mac OS X)**
**~ / Arduino / (Linux)**
Este directorio se conoce como "Sketchbook" y contiene los bocetos del usuario. La ruta se puede cambiar a través de la preferencia **sketchbook.path** .

Además de bocetos, tres directorios especiales pueden estar dentro del cuaderno de bocetos:

**bibliotecas**
Las bibliotecas pueden colocarse dentro de este directorio, una biblioteca por subdirectorio.

**hardware**
Se puede agregar soporte para hardware de terceros a través de este directorio.

**herramientas**
Las herramientas de procesamiento de código externo (que se pueden ejecutar a través del menú Herramientas del IDE) se pueden agregar aquí.

- **EJEMPLOS**

Inicie Arduino IDE, con dos archivos abiertos:

`arduino /path/to/sketch/sketch.ino /path/to/sketch/extra.ino`

Compile y cargue un boceto utilizando la última placa y puerto serie seleccionados

`arduino --upload /path/to/sketch/sketch.ino`

Compila y sube un boceto a un Arduino Nano, con una CPU Atmega168, conectada al puerto / dev / ttyACM0 :

`arduino --board arduino: avr: nano: cpu = atmega168 --port / dev / ttyACM0 --upload /path/to/sketch/sketch.ino`

Compile un boceto, coloque los resultados de compilación en el directorio de compilación y reutilice los resultados de compilación previos en ese directorio.

`arduino --pref build.path = / ruta / a / boceto / compilación --verify /path/to/sketch/sketch.ino`

Cambie la tabla y la ruta de compilación seleccionadas y no haga nada más.

`arduino --pref build.path = / ruta / a / boceto / compilación --board arduino: avr: uno --save-prefs`

Instale el soporte más reciente de la placa SAM

`arduino --install-boards "arduino: sam"`

Instalar el soporte de la placa AVR, 1.6.2

`arduino --install-boards "arduino: avr: 1.6.2"`

Instalar la biblioteca Bridge versión 1.0.0

`arduino --install-library "Bridge: 1.0.0"`

Instalar bibliotecas Bridge y Servo

`arduino --install-library "Bridge: 1.0.0, Servo: 1.2.0"`

- **HISTORIA**

**1.5.2**
Se agregó soporte de línea de comandos inicial. Esto introdujo --verify , --upload , **--board** , **--port** , **--verbose** y **-v** .

**1.5.5**
Se agregó soporte para los parámetros específicos de la placa a **--board** .

Los nombres de los archivos de bosquejo ahora se interpretan en relación con el directorio actual en lugar de la ubicación del comando arduino.

**1.5.6**
Introdujo **--pref** , **--preferences-file** , **--verbose-build** y **--verbose-upload** .

Las preferencias establecidas a través de --pref se recuerdan, las preferencias establecidas a través de **--board** , **--port** o las opciones **--verbose** no lo son.

Cuando se ejecuta con **--verify** o **--upload** , ya no se muestra la GUI completa. Los mensajes de error todavía usan una ventana emergente gráfica y en Windows, la pantalla de inicio aún se muestra.

**1.5.8**
Introdujo **--save-prefs** .

**1.6.2**
El ejecutable principal en MacOS X cambió de Arduino.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub a Arduino.app/Contents/MacOS/Arduino .

**1.6.4**
Introdujo **--install-boards** y **--install-library** .

- las opciones de prefijo no se guardan ahora en el archivo de preferencias, al igual que **--board** y **--port** , a menos que se especifique **--save-prefs** .

Una ruta pasada a **--preferences-file** , o set in the build.path , preferences.path o settings.path ahora se interpreta en relación con el directorio actual en lugar de la ubicación del comando arduino.

- **RECURSOS**

Sitio web: [http://www.arduino.cc/](https://www.arduino.cc/)
Ayuda en proyectos y programación:http://forum.arduino.cc/
Informar errores:https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues
Lista de correo de desarrollo de IDE y framework:https://groups.google.com/a/arduino.cc/forum/#!forum/developers

Puedes encontrar esta informacion en ingles en: [ARDUINO (1) Página de manual](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/build/shared/manpage.adoc)